# Why can't I get my JavaScript replace function to work?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying for quite a while to get my text to replace and it just hasn't been replacing anything no matter what I try. I've tried searching everywhere but I can't find an answer.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>OnStream</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://onstreamvideo.github.io/css/style.css">

</head>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =
                    document.getElementById("sharingurl").value;

    }
  </script>

  <script>
  function fetchCorrections() {
    var str = document.getElementById("sharingurl").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace(/www.google.com/g, "google");
    document.getElementById("sharingurl").innerHTML = str;


}
    </script>



  <body onload="fetchCorrections();">
<header>
  <h1>OnStream</h1>
</header>
</body>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <form>
        Dropbox Share Url:<br>
  <input type="text" id="sharingurl" value="url"><br><br>

<input type="button" onclick="showInput();" value="Click"><br/>
  <br>
</form>
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>
  <label>Your Input</label>
  <p><span id='display'</span></p>
</li>
<ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to Stack Overflow and coding in general so please excuse my ignorance if I made a mistake. :)

EDIT:
Sorry guys, I'm tired and I've been working on this randomly throughout the day trying to pick up where I left off each time and I left a few errors in my code before posting. I tried cleaning up my code a little bit, and I've swapped the code above for the newer more clean code; if you see any mistakes feel free to let me know and just understand it was a clumsy mistake on my part. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have multiple `<headers>` and `<body>`. And in your js, you are reassigning to `str`

Comment: Your markup is riddled with errors. Multiple `body` tags, lots of unclosed elements (`<p>`, `<span>`, `<ul>`). Try to fix that first and I can help you out

Comment: logic has errors too ... an `<input>` has no innerHTML...it has value

Comment: You have markup errors. Like others said fix your markup first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, it will work

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>OnStream</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://onstreamvideo.github.io/css/style.css">
</head>
<script language="JavaScript">
  function showInput() {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =
      document.getElementById("sharingurl").value;
  }

  function fetchCorrections() {
    showInput();
    var str = document.getElementById("sharingurl").value;
    var res = str.replace(/blue/g, "red");
    document.getElementById("sharingurl").value = res;
  }
</script>

<body class="depiction">
  <header>
    <h1>OnStream</h1>
  </header>
</body>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <form>
        Dropbox Share Url:
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="sharingurl" value="url">
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="button" onclick="fetchCorrections()" value="Click">
        <br/>
        <br>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Your Input</label>
      <p><span id='display' </p>
</li>
<ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should really test it yourself

Comment: I'm trying to give a solution to what was asked

Comment: i understand that but get an input element and try it yourself and you will find it won't work

Comment: @nathanaccidentally what's the problem now ?

Comment: @nathanaccidentally sorry i edited it in debugger but didn't make final changes in the file

Comment: @nathanaccidentally I've edited it again. Check it out

Comment: It works when replacing text in the input field, but not the output. I've gotten it to work now though thanks to your help! :) All I needed to do was run showInput() with onclick for the button so it refreshes and shows in the output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes in your programs

1. Span with id= display is incomplete.
2. Input element doesn't have property like innerHTML.
3. You should use value property instead of innerHTML to assign value in input element.
4. multiple body tags.

And try to replace this function with fetchcorrection

```
function fetchCorrection(){
    var str = document.getElementById("sharingurl").value;
    var res = str.replace(/blue/g, "red");
    document.getElementById("sharingurl").value = res;
}
```